# Changing the subject of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we change the subject of the equation from $x \to y$?

For 
$$x^{3/2}=y^{3/2}+ay^{-1/2}$$ where $a$ is some constant?

Comment: What is the "subject of the equation"?

Comment: @AlexBecker: Sorry maybe I got the wrong word... I meant making $y$ the left hand side variable so that we have an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: in other words, how can we find $y=y(x)$ explicitly?

Comment: Where does this show up? What do you want to do with the explicit formula for $y$ in terms of $x$? Often one can go around such need by computing differently.

Comment: @vonbrand: I want to get a second order approximation of $y$ in $x$.

Comment: @Greta, a few steps of e.g. Newton's method should get you there. For _what_ $x$? Large, small, ...?

Comment: @vonbrand: small $x$. What is "Newton's method"? (Just in case, I think I should mention: I wish to find a series expansion of $y(x)$ -- not by numerical means though)

Comment: @Greta, I feel we have too little information on where this comes from, and what you want to do with the result, to be able to give a sensible, useful answer. Partial answer: Write $y^2 = x^{3/2} y^{1/2} - a$, if $x \approx 0$ then $y \approx \sqrt{-a}$, so $y^2 \approx x^{3/2} \sqrt[4]{-a} - a$ should give a better approximation. Rinse and repeat. Probably an expansion of $y^2$ in terms of $x^{3/2}$ is easiest (if useful, that is).

Answer (score 1):

If the equation was 
$x^{3/2}=y^{3/2}+ay^{-3/2}$
or
$x^{3/2}=y^{1/2}+ay^{-1/2}$,
or
$x^{s}=y^{r}+ay^{-r}$
for any positive reals $r$ and $s$,
we could solve for $y$ in terms of $x$
by solving a quadratic.

Your example involves solving a quartic,
which is oodles messier.

To solve 
$x^{s}=y^{r}+ay^{-r}$,
let $u = x^{s}$ and $v = y^{r}$.
This becomes
$u = v + a/v$
or
$uv = v^2+a$
or $v^2-uv+a=0$.
This simple quadratic
is readily solved for $v$ in terms
of $u$ and $a$,
remembering to worry about the
sign of the square root.
Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ is then easy.

Comment: Thanks marty :) @vonbrand mentioned finding $y$ as a series of $x$. How might that be done?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it just can't be done. Here you can rewrite:
$$
y^2 - x^{3/2} y^{1/2} + a = 0
$$
This is a (depressed) [quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) in $y^{1/2}$, so there is a known explicit formula for its roots. But it is a very complicated expression (you could ask [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) or some other computer algebra system for it).

Depending on what you want, you could use a numerical method to compute $y$ given $x$, or get a series for $y$ in $x$, or something else.

Comment: Thanks, vonbrand :) How might I get the series for $y$ in $x$?

Comment: The [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) gives its coefficients in some cases with not _too_ horrible formulas. But I wouldn't go there unless I'd need it in that form. If you need to compute values, a numerical method is the most practical way.

Comment: @vonbrand if I'm just looking for a parameterization of the above equation, would it be possible?